# Make a button move with a cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet in which I need a button in each row to stamp the time in the cell next to it and then sort the rows in order of time. My problem is that the buttons do not move. E.g. Button in cell B1 changes time in cell A1 and button in cell B2 changes time in cell A2 and for this example lets say A2 has a lower time than A1 so when sorted A1 and A2 effectively swap data. Now the button in B2 changes the time in cell A1.

Been trying to figure this out for hours, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just have *one* button that does all the work based on whatever cell is currently *selected*?

Comment: Ah that would work, how do I do that?

Comment: How would you do what, exactly?

Comment: You haven't shown any code, but it sounds like you should look into `activecell`

Answer (score 1):

Based on David's comment, you can try this set up.

```
Dim r As Range
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    r.Offset(0, -1).Value = Time
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then GoTo moveon
    Dim btn As OLEObject: Set btn = Me.OLEObjects("CommandButton21")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Set r = Target
        With btn
            .Visible = True
            .Left = r.Left
            .Top = r.Top
            .Width = r.Width
            .Height = r.Height
        End With
    Else
        btn.Visible = False
    End If

moveon:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume moveon
End Sub
```

You need to create an ActiveX Control with `CommandButton21` as its name.
This buttons move and appear when something is selected in Column B.
You can add your sort routine on the *CommandButton21_Click* event.